# Mysql fetch PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM family WHERE family = '$family'";
                $result = mysql_query($sqll)or die(mysql_error());
```

Is this the right way to get php variable into mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could work. However, it's vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This is safer:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT email FROM family WHERE family = '%s'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($family));
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you starting with PHP/MySQL I would recommend you to check [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension as it allows you to use more smart database queries and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The code has a type error

`$sqll` is not defined.it must be `$result = mysql_query($sql)`.

I believe this is the reason you are looking for...(since the question is too vague which is probably because you got an error that you couldnt track)

Answer (score -1):

From my knowledge best way to use like this:

if $family is not string

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM family WHERE family = ".$family;
```

if there is a string comparison then,

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM family WHERE family = '".$family."'";
```

Comment: Either case is seriously dangerous with out emphasizing sanitizing inputs. Really though the developer shouldn't have to worry about that, just put a ? in it's place and use bound parameters or PDO instead.

Comment: @Mischa He is in confusion. He asked what is the right way so from my knowledge i just try to help him nothing else.

Comment: @srbhbarot Although your intention is good, you're not addressing the problem with the solution. Your code looks vulnerable to SQL injections, which probably is the reason you got downvoted.

Answer (score -2):

`'$family'` no need of single quotes here

Comment: Yes there is... (assuming `$family` is a string)